# Undo Button for a WordSearch app

Tags: android, textview, undo

I'm new to android and I'm having a hard time finding solutions to my problem on my app.

My app is a wordsearch game that uses tapping on the tiles as an input. This is the code for the `onClick()` of the dynamic *textviews* on the tablelayout:

```
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    w.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    //change the color of tapped textview

                    text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(mColors[randomNum]));

                    String b = text.getText().toString();

                    uTxt.setText(""+uTxt.getText().toString() + b);

                    //check if answer is in the word grid


                    if(checkAns(uTxt, list))
                    {


                        w.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        wC.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(wC.getText()+"")-1));

                        if(Integer.parseInt(wC.getText()+"") == 0){

                            int newM = minutes*60 + seconds;
                            dataHelper.insertData(pNameC.getText().toString(), newM, currentDateandTime, Category.leve);

                            t.cancel();
                            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
                            Activity mActivity = GameScreen.this;
                            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                            // Inflate the custom layout/view
                            View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gameover,null);

                            // Initialize a new instance of popup window
                            PopupWindow mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                                    customView,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                            );

                            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "raw2.ttf");
                            TextView cattxt = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.catTxt);


                            String ctg = ti.getText().toString();

                            cattxt.setTypeface(font);
                            cattxt.setText(ctg);



                            Button yesB = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.maglaro2);
                            yesB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(GameScreen.this, Category.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
                                    GameScreen.this.finish();
                                }
                            });

                            Button noB = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.hindi);
                            noB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(GameScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
                                    GameScreen.this.finish();
                                }
                            });

                            mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(table, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                        }
                        uTxt.setText("");

                    }




                    }

            });
```

Now my problem is I want an UNDO Button that will delete the last character on the `uTxt` and will change back the color of the last touched `textView`

**Does anyone have any ideas on how to do that?**

If yes leave a comment, answer, or suggestion below. TIA!

Comment: Have you heard of a stack?

Comment: @RobertColumbia not yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Typical solution for this problem is the usage of the command pattern (excellent for undo redo functionality).
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern